# How to get parameters of a step with multiple pipelines in cucumber for the java code?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, gherkin

I have below steps in my feature file for a scenario.

```
Given my_first_step

And my_second_step
  | Themes          | one | three |

  | Service Windows | two | four  |

And my_third_step

  | Create Apps |

  | Config      |
```

we can get parameters of 'my_third_step' as below in the java code as a list

public void my_third_step(List listOfItems) {}

but how can get parameters in 'my_second_step' ? 
I need to get a rows as array of elements in the java code. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a list of objects, your object will look like

```
public class MyObject {
    private Integer themes;
    private Integer service;

    public Integer getThemes() {
       return this.themes;
    }

    public void setThemes(Integer themes) {
       this.themes = themes;
    }

    public Integer getService() {
       return this.service;
    }

    public void setService(Integer service) {
       this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Then you can pass a `List<MyObject>` to the method.

```
public void my_second_step(List<MyObject>) {
...
}
```

In the feature file change the definition as follows:

```
And my_second_step
  | Themes          | Service |
  | one             | two     |
  | three           | four    |
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Found a solution from this approach. I am going to use list of lists. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using **Header** we can implement Data Table in much clean & precise way and considering Data Table looks like below one -

```
And my_second_step
    | Heading_1        | Heading_2 | Heading_3 | 
    |  Themes          |    one    | three     |
    |  Service Windows |    two    | four      |

public void my_second_step(DataTable table) throws Throwable {

List<Map<String, String>> list = table.asMaps(String.class,String.class); 

System.out.println(list.get(0).get("Heading_1") + " : " + list.get(1).get("Heading_1"));
System.out.println(list.get(0).get("Heading_2") + " : " + list.get(1).get("Heading_2"));
System.out.println(list.get(0).get("Heading_3") + " : " + list.get(1).get("Heading_3"));

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer 'TheSociety'. I used the DataTables as you mentioned. but that giving me below error.

Comment: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Could not convert arguments for step [the group {string} has the following permissions] defined at 'com.symbox.stepdefs.iam.iamManagePermissionGroupPageStepDef.theGroupHasTheFollowingPermissions(String,DataTable) in file:/D:/SDBPTestAutomation/SDBP-Automation/sdbp-automated-tests/automation-framework/target/test-classes/'.
It appears you did not register a data table type. The details are in the stacktrace below.

Comment: Caused by: io.cucumber.datatable.UndefinedDataTableTypeException: Can't convert DataTable to cucumber.api.DataTable.
Please register a DataTableType with a TableTransformer, TableEntryTransformer or TableRowTransformer for cucumber.api.DataTable.

Comment: Ohh finally found a way to do it . I am going to use List<List<String>>. That seems like working.
Thanks